# How much time does it take to finish a job on AWS spot instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

This question might seem very general, but it might be helpful when we want to choose between spot and on-demand instances.

I'm new to AWS.

Let's say I have a job that I want to run on a spot instance with an expected interruption rate of *alpha* (5 percent for example). On an on-demand instance of the same type, it take *t*  minutes to complete the job. Now I have the following questions:

1. What does the interruption rate exactly mean? It must have something to do with the duration of using the instance. For example, if you use the spot instance for 1 hour, there is less chance to be interrupted compared to a situation where you plan to use it for 2 hours. But interruption rate is expressed as a fixed number. What does it exactly represent?
2. If the instance gets interrupted, is there an option for automatically submitting a request for a new spot instance of the same type in the same availability zone? In that case how much time does it take on average to get a new instance? Can it be estimated using the interruption rate (In other words, is the interruption period somehow correlated to interruption rate)?
3. If I restrict myself to only one type of instance in one availability zone, can I somehow estimate the amount of time it takes to finish the job on a spot instance? I suppose that I know the amount of time it takes to finish the job on an on-demand instance of the same type, plus, I save the job's status very frequently.

Comment: The interruption rate is the percent of interruptions over the previous month.  Also note, it bottoms out at 5%, so an interruption every week is the same as no interruptions.  You can setup an ASG with spot instances, but if you don't have a wide variety of instance types in the group, you might not get any instances (and even if you do have a wide variety, there still not may be availability, that value doesn't include "no-capacity" errors).  Spot instances and On Demand instances are the same hardware, so if a task takes 1 hour on on demand, it'll take one hour on spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in details let's follow the concepts in peaces:

> 1. What does the interruption rate exactly mean? It must have something to do with the duration of using the instance. For example, if you use the spot instance for 1 hour, there is less chance to be interrupted compared to a situation where you plan to use it for 2 hours. But interruption rate is expressed as a fixed number. What does it exactly represent?

When you go to https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/ it would show you some details about the instances type and its interruption rates.
Interruption rates or Frequency of interruption means that from all spot instances that were requested in the last 30 days (regardless of duration) around x% of time, they had to be reclaimed.

> From: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/ Frequency of interruption represents the rate at which Spot has reclaimed capacity during the trailing month. They are in ranges of < 5%, 5-10%, 10-15%, 15-20% and >20%.

If you had to picture this, Imagine that you take a train with 50% ticket discount with the only caveat that if the train gets full and another person who paid the full price of the ticket wants to go in, you have to get out of the train (so you allow this person to get in without modifying capacity).
Finally, if 4 out of 20 trips you take (regardless of distance traveled) would represent 20% of your trips were "reclaimed".

Conclusion: it doesn't matter how long your job needs to run, if you choose a specific ec2 size for your spot, this has it's percentage rate at which you might get interrupted.

[image]

[image]

- in us-east-1 i3.large spot instances have >20% chance of getting reclaimed
- in us-east-1 i4g.large spot instances have <5% change of getting reclaimed

given similarities in specs, you should choose i4g.large

> 2. If the instance gets interrupted, is there an option for automatically submitting a request for a new spot instance of the same type in the same availability zone? In that case how much time does it take on average to get a new instance? Can it be estimated using the interruption rate (In other words, is the interruption period somehow correlated to interruption rate)?

There is no evidence or documentation on that but, in theory, if your instance were reclaimed, that also means there are more "on-demand" instances allocated so there are no more free instances of that type. You can request a new spot of that exact same type, but the time to get that new spot would only depend on some other instance (either on-demand or another spot) to finish it's job giving one free space for you. There is no way to calculate that time on that specific moment.

If you had to picture that too, imagine that train we talked about before is at peak hour traffic, you don't have a way to tell when the peak time would be over, so if you want that exact same train, you'll have to wait indefinitely.

> If I restrict myself to only one type of instance in one availability zone, can I somehow estimate the amount of time it takes to finish the job on a spot instance? I suppose that I know the amount of time it takes to finish the job on an on-demand instance of the same type, plus, I save the job's status very frequently.

Restricting your job to one type of instance would do the opposite, as you'll have fewer choices to take in order to allow other instance types to be available for you.

Picturing this, it would be better for you to have different train options whenever you get kicked out of one specific type, so you might have a chance to take a longer route to your destination but at least keep moving instead of waiting for that exact same train keeping you stuck at that station.

This also applies no only for same instance types but regions, but whenever you change regions you might also need to consider transfer data costs so... keep that in mind.

One more thing, you might want to also consider changing from spot to on-demand instances whenever you don't have more spot instances available for you (like if you've been waiting for 5 minutes). This should allow you to better predict your job duration since it's going to benefit from spot only if available.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Regarding the answer to the third question, I know that I can use other choices. My question is that "in case I restrict myself to only one type of instance" how can I estimate the time needed to finish the job.

Comment: because of the conclusion of question 2, once the EC2 was in fact reclaimed, there is no way to calculate the amount of time it would take for another of that same type to be available. There is no error message suggesting when it would be back nor metric to follow.
You'll be stuck on a loop indefinitely until one other EC2 gets free.

Answer (score 1):

When a spot instance is interrupted, it is normally an indication that the number of 'spare' instances of that type is too small and they have been reassigned for use for non-spot use (eg on-demand use). Therefore, it is **not a good idea to restrict yourself** to "only one type of instance in one availability zone" since they are likely to be in short-supply.

If you are willing to use another AZ or another instance type, there would likely be plenty of capacity.

This is the core concept of [Spot Fleet - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html):

> A **Spot Fleet** is a set of Spot Instances and optionally On-Demand Instances that is launched based on criteria that you specify. The Spot Fleet selects the Spot capacity pools that meet your needs and launches Spot Instances to **meet the target capacity** for the fleet. By default, Spot Fleets are set to **maintain target capacity by launching replacement instances** after Spot Instances in the fleet are terminated.

The potential cost savings from using Spot Instances is huge, so the occasional termination (with automatic replacement via Spot Fleet) trades a little inconvenience for large potential cost saving.